JavaRX buffering from many kafka topics and fault tolerancy
I am consuming from couple of kafka topics within JavaRX. I have groupping per key + 3s buffer window. I dont know how to 'not' commit message which is inside buffer window process and another message in different buffer (diff. kafka key) caused severe error. During redeployment I hope this message inside buffer should be again processed and not lost.
Any idea for compensation or commiting?
Manual committing is tricky since I am consuming from 10 topics.
